# which application is needed to read genesis rom files

Tags: nodejs

I had downloaded node.js in my ubuntu 11.10. When i had unzipped and pretend to open README.md, it prompts me that ' there is no application installed for genesis rom files. Please help me by sharing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In README.md , md stands for `markdown`. I have found a script which can help you to view the mark down files .

```
import os
import sys

MARKDOWN = 'markdown'
UPSKIRT = 'upskirt'

PROGRAM = MARKDOWN
VERBOSE = True

def main():
    update = False

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print "Usage: {0} <file.markdown> [-u]".format(sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(1)
    # else
    if '-u' in sys.argv:
        update = True
        sys.argv.remove('-u')
    input_file = sys.argv[1]
    os.system("{program} {input} > /tmp/markdown.html".format(program=PROGRAM, input=input_file))
    if not update:
        os.system("chromium-browser /tmp/markdown.html &")
    if VERBOSE:
        print >>sys.stderr, "# renderer: {0}".format(PROGRAM)

#############################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How to use this :

> put it in your ~/bin directory (make sure ~/bin is in your PATH), make
>   it executable (chmod u+x ~/bin/markdown.py), and call it as
>   “markdown.py README.markdown“. It will open the HTML output in a new
>   tab. Adding the “-u” switch (update), the HTML is not opened in the
>   browser.

credit goes here:  [ubuntuincident.wordpress.com](http://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/readme-markdown-on-github/)

Answer (score 0):

So, you're asking two different questions here.

.MD is markdown, not a genesis rom file. Markdown is a text format and there's a [couple](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465763/how-to-install-the-gedit-markdown-preview-plugin-on-14-04) answers here

For the second part, the genesis rom file, you'll need an emulator like [dgen](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dgen)