# How to install the gedit markdown-preview plugin on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, python, gedit, plugins

I've just installed the markdown preview plugin for **gedit** and I get the following error on the console when I try to activate it in the plugins tab:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/aarold/.local/share/gedit/plugins/markdown-preview/**init**.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       import markdown ImportError: No module named 'markdown'
>
> (gedit:20735): libpeas-WARNING **: Error loading plugin
>   'markdown-preview

### ***Note that this is not the same question as the other one about gedit since its solution does not work for me.***

I've tried setting the *Loader* parameter in my `/home/aarold/.local/share/gedit/plugins/markdown-preview.plugin` file to `python` and `python3` as well but none of them work. I tried reinstalling the plugin with all possible permutations of options and although it says install was succesful I always get this error. What could be the problem?

I've checked the `.py` file and it seems that it cannot

`import markdown`.

Do I need to install some additional python modules?

I've tried

```
pip install markdown
```

but although it

> Successfully installed markdown

I still get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This plugin is written for Python 2, but since gedit 3.8, only Python 3 plugins are supported. So some small changes are required.

1. Modify the installer (`gedit-markdown.sh`) to install the python3 markdown module:

   This is a patch that you can apply on the existing file (or you can just copy the full modified version available [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7462838/)):

   ```
   --- gedit-markdown_ori.sh   2014-05-14 16:14:58.386700310 +0200
   +++ gedit-markdown.sh   2014-05-14 15:42:21.038783248 +0200
   @@ -263,7 +263,9 @@

    # Note: sous Archlinux, «/usr/bin/python» correspond à Python 3. On teste donc les
    # chemins pour Python 2 en premier.
   -if type -p python2.7 > /dev/null; then
   +if type -p python3 > /dev/null; then
   +   binPython=$(type -p python3)
   +elif type -p python2.7 > /dev/null; then
       binPython=$(type -p python2.7)
    elif type -p python2.6 > /dev/null; then
       binPython=$(type -p python2.6)
   @@ -287,15 +289,15 @@
               cheminPythonMarkdown=python-markdown/python2
               cheminPythonSitePackages=$("$binPython" -m site --user-site)
           fi
   -#  elif [[ ${versionPython:0:1} == 3 ]]; then
   -#      compareVersions "$versionPython" "3.1"
   -#      
   -#      if [[ $? == 2 ]]; then
   -#          bonneVersionPython=false
   -#      else
   -#          cheminPythonMarkdown=python-markdown/python3
   -#          cheminPythonSitePackages=$("$binPython" -m site --user-site)
   -#      fi
   +   elif [[ ${versionPython:0:1} == 3 ]]; then
   +       compareVersions "$versionPython" "3.1"
   +       
   +       if [[ $? == 2 ]]; then
   +           bonneVersionPython=false
   +       else
   +           cheminPythonMarkdown=python-markdown/python3
   +           cheminPythonSitePackages=$("$binPython" -m site --user-site)
   +       fi
       else
           bonneVersionPython=false
       fi
   ```
2. Run `./gedit-markdown.sh install`

   You should see python 3.4 instead of 2.7:

   ```
   ############################################################
   ##
   ## Installation of gedit-markdown
   ##
   ############################################################

   ## First step: check dependencies

   - gedit: 3.10.4
   - Python: 3.4

   [...]
   ```
3. Change the plugin loader to python3

   Replace `/home/aarold/.local/share/gedit/plugins/markdown-preview.plugin` with:

   ```
   [Plugin]
   Loader=python3
   Module=markdown-preview
   IAge=3
   Name=Markdown Preview
   Name[fr]=Aperçu Markdown
   Description=Show the HTML version of the Markdown text you're editing
   Description[fr]=Affiche l'aperçu en HTML du document Markdown en cours d'édition
   Authors=Michele Campeotto <micampe@micampe.it>\nJean-Philippe Fleury <contact@jpfleury.net>
   Copyright=Copyright © 2005, 2006 Michele Campeotto\nCopyright © 2009, 2011-2012 Jean-Philippe Fleury
   Website=http://www.jpfleury.net/logiciels/gedit-markdown.php
   ```
4. Convert `/home/aarold/.local/share/gedit/plugins/markdown-preview/__init__.py` to python3:

   Run:

   ```
   2to3 -w /home/aarold/.local/share/gedit/plugins/markdown-preview/__init__.py
   ```

   Finally open this file and edit line 86 (remove the binary mode, `"wb"` -> `"w"`):

   ```
   with open(confFile, "w") as confFile:
   ```
5. Activate the plugin in Gedit as you did.

Comment: Many thanks, this helped me solving my problem (arch derivate) with this plugin; although I also had to remove `.decode("utf-8")` in `__init__.py` line 382 because of an AttributeError. It seems that from python3.x this method is removed and 2to3 does not recognize...

Comment: @32bitfloat, good to know, thanks for your contribution

Comment: I've unisntalled it and try to install it again with the new gedit-markdown.sh but I've a error "Permission not allowed"
(Sorry I tried to write a comment)

Comment: I can confirm that the solution works - but only after removing .decode("utf-8") in __init__.py line 382. Ctrl-Alt-V toggles Markdown-Preview window and Ctrl-Alr-M to update Preview.